# Google App Engine map /foo to /

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this web app and the very first page that loads is the login page:

**app.appspot.com**

after successfully login the app redirects to:

**app.appspot.com\foo**

I'd like to know if there is a way to map

**app.appspot.com\foo** to **app.appspot.com**

**UPDATE**

Here's my app.yaml:

```
handlers:

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css
- url: /fonts
  static_dir: static/fonts
- url: /img
  static_dir: static/img
- url: .*
  script: handler.app
  secure: always
```

Comment: Please share your `app.yaml` file?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you're using the python environment.

You could have a `login_required` decorator to check if the user is logged in, redirect to a login page if not and then back after login completes. An example of such decorator which uses the GAE `users` API as authentication method can be found in [webapp2_extras.appengine.users](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/webapp2_extras/appengine/users.html):

```
from google.appengine.api import users

def login_required(handler_method):
    """A decorator to require that a user be logged in to access a handler.

    To use it, decorate your get() method like this::

        @login_required
        def get(self):
            user = users.get_current_user(self)
            self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.nickname())

    We will redirect to a login page if the user is not logged in. We always
    redirect to the request URI, and Google Accounts only redirects back as
    a GET request, so this should not be used for POSTs.
    """
    def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method != 'GET':
            self.abort(400,
                       detail='The login_required decorator '
                              'can only be used for GET requests.')

        user = users.get_current_user()
        if not user:
            return self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.url))
        else:
            handler_method(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return check_login
```

You could map your handler currently handling the '/foo' path to '/' and apply such decorator to its `get()` method, obtaining the result you desire (your decorator would actually perform the login function by your '/' current handler).

And you can apply such decorator to any other handler/path in your app.